# Health check for samba domain controller, which does more than port checking

Tags: samba, monitoring

Usually in a http(s) world an health check would be implemented with a http(s) url check, like `curl https://my.host.com/health`  and this would return a status indicating the health.

A Samba Domain Controller is based on an older technology, so I can't send http(s) request to check for its health, but I could use nc (netcat) to at least connect and check if a service is listening. My question is a little more than that, is it possible to send  the various ports of a samba domain controller a "status" or "noop" command sequence, so that actually I can determine with the reply, that the service is runnning. 
I do not mind if that would be binary, as long it would give an useful response, telling more than *"a service connected to this port*", but actually this is a "samba service" connected the port, according to response.

Comment: Are you running an Active Directory domain controller or a legacy NT4 one?

Comment: samba domain controller 4.9.1